# Elegant way to print the pattern into single awk or sed command

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking for a pattern and want the First line to be printed from that searched pattern, though i can do that via sed & awk but looking for a shorted one liner , i tried below two way which is producing a entire output ..

```
# dmidecode | awk 'NR == 1 || /Product/'
# dmidecode 3.0
        Product Name: SYS-749P-TR
        Product Name: X11DPi-N
        Product Name: SYS-7049P-TR
        Product Name: X11DPi-N
```

Second:

```
# dmidecode | awk '/Product/ || NR == 1'
# dmidecode 3.0
        Product Name: SYS-749P-TR
        Product Name: X11DPi-N
        Product Name: SYS-7049P-TR
        Product Name: X11DPi-N
```

While using via multi-piped way it works.

```
# dmidecode | awk '/Product/' | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'
Product Name: SYS-749P-TR

# dmidecode | grep Product | sed -n 1p
Product Name: SYS-749P-TR
```

Comment: Please post your sample Input_file and expected output in CODE TAGS, since you claimed that posted answer is not working(which was given as per your ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the third field on the first line that contains `Product`.  If that is the case, try:

```
dmidecode | awk '/Product/{print $3;exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following once and let me know if that helps:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 || (/Product/ && ++count==1)'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Only in case you want to look for first occurrence of `Product` along with the first line of Input_file then come out of the Input_file then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 || /Product/{print;exit}'  Input_file
```

Comment: both did not worked, though changing `FNR == 2` for the first  action you given that works, but its not processing the `pattern` search correctly as it only printing the `# dmidecode 3.0`.

Comment: @donovan, command was given as per your ask, please do show your sample Input_file and expected output in CODE TAGS, I will tune it then as per your need too.